# How do I serve a client app from a separate nginx service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to separate out my services using docker-compose. I essentially want 3 separate services:

1. nginx
2. flask-api
3. client

Right now my client `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-react-app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install --silent
COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/client
COPY --from=build-react-app /app/build/ /var/www/client/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I'd prefer to have my nginx steps as a separate service. If I do this, how do I move my client code into the `/var/www/client/` folder to be served by nginx?

Comment: What's not working about the Dockerfile you posted?

Comment: I was able to get it working. I will post the updated setup.